# AttributError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'exc_info'

Tags: django

I am facing the following error in my Django project when I run on staging, but I face no error on my local machine:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f28cb57e500>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/thakurani/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    _exception = sys.exc_info()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'exc_info'
```

Comment: So how did you manage to define sys to None? Show the full trace.

Comment: How can I have the full trace? I get this error on my staging server when I quit the server in a tmux session. I don't get the full trace there.@Melvyn

Comment: Can you shed some light on when does **sys** become None? @Melvyn

Comment: Ok, that may be garbage collection. What are the steps to reproduce? Activate virtualenv, python manage runserver, then press ctrl-c and you get the error?

Comment: Yes, after I run python manage.py runserver and I try to access the website from my web browser but fail to connect to the site, and then I press ctrl-c.@Melvyn

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to worry about, albeit a bit confusing. The reload functionality triggers if any of the python files are modified. If you hit ctrl-c while reload is running, the sys module is already unloaded and the variable undefined when the exception is triggered.

In fact, it probably triggers on KeyboardInterrupt, since it catches all exceptions. If you're able to trigger this 100% of the time, it is a bit weird - that would mean your files are constantly being modified or autoreload triggered some other way.

Since it's impossible to get a real trace there and it's threaded, it will be extremely hard to get to the bottom of the issue.

Comment: I don't think this is about modification, this happens to me on exit. Python objects including modules get unloaded and then some lagging threads get into this.